# Am I allowed to write an essay about a scientific theory without violating the copyright?

Tags: writing, copyright, legal-issues

I have in project to write an essay on the Special Theory of Relativity. My idea is then to publish it as an ebook.

I would like to know if I can freely write about this topic or I need to take into account some problems related to royalties or copyright. Can I write about a topic like that without any problems of this kind? Can I include quotes and information about Einstein's life?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *freely*? Don't you want to provide references in your publication?

Comment: You must cite any and all work that is not your own - this includes quotes, biographies and such. Otherwise it is plagiarism.

Comment: With _freely_ I mean without having issues in term of royalties; I obviously would like to provide references or the source of every quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

Scientific principles are **never** subject to copyright—you cannot copyright a scientific idea, theory, equation, or concept.

That said, you *do* have to worry about copyright if you extensively quote from copyrighted primary or secondary resources as part of your text. If you are not directly using their language, then you need only cite the works, and no royalty or copyright issues should arise.

(Note that in the particular case of the special theory of relativity, it is more than 95 years old (as it was announced in 1905), and thus [is no longer under US copyright protection](https://copyright.cornell.edu/resources/publicdomain.cfm) in any event, so you could in principle reuse or even reprint the entire text of his article.)

Comment: Note that Einstein’s works (if published in Germany) are still under German copyright protection until 01.01.2026 (70 calendar years after his death), if I am not fully mistaken.

Comment: Your unequivocal answer is muddled by your appeal to the age of the theory, rather than the age of the paper.  The *content of the theory* is never subject to copyright.  The *text of any article* written about it is subject to copyright, but that copyright may have expired by now.

Comment: *you could in principle reuse or even reprint the entire text of his article*, but you still need to make clear it's not your text, or you are guilty of plagiarism.

Comment: @gerrit: True, but the question was about royalty or copyright issues, not plagiarism issues.